# table is full in innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

One of the table t_keyword_stat_ga in the my DB on server(currently the master) was set as INT for a column `id`. This column is also set as the auto_increment. As noticed today the INT column reached its maximum allowable range for a value i.e. 2147483647 (the column by default is signed). Now the auto_increment detects the maximum value, but it doesnt have a mechanism to report any error or warnings related to that, instead as noticed later, it inserted new records with the same `id` value i.e. 2147483647, for almost 1.77Million records.

Following this, updates queries ran updating any row with `id` 2147483647, unfortunately there were 1.7M of them, this caused all those statement to be logged in binary logs in "Row" format (current binlog format is mixed, however mysql will choose "row" based for Update statements). This instantly filled up the disks containing binary logs (every update changed 1.7M rows). And the slaves were unable to cope up with this much data, and that filled up the relay logs volume on them too. This caused us to reset the slaves with a plan to re-build them again in future (Once master is fixed).

We have changed the `id` column type from INT to BIGINT to allow a larger range for the integer values. However, the auto_increment behavior made us to execute the Alter again to initialise it to a proper start point i.e. 2147483648. As per the mysql documentation the auto_increment will get the maximum value currently in the column and then start with that value + 1. However, when we tested the same behavior with a test table, we found that auto_increment will start with value as follows :

start value = (current max value for the column) + (number of rows in the table) + 1

This unusual behavior could have resulted in large gaps in auto_increment, which would not be beneficial to client (especially with any queries where they use a range condition based on `id` column).

Comment: Please help me to how to fix this issue .i cant able to alter because it is a huge data table.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you have? The docs for 5.1 say that once the autoincrement max has been reached, stuff should fail not insert with the same max id. (Please also clean up your tags or title. One says MyISAM, the other InnoDB, and you talk about something called DB2 in the text which is confusing.)

Comment: i am using mysql 5.1

Comment: Are there FKs in other tables that are referencing this `id`?

Comment: There is no FKs relationship with other tables.if it having Fk relationship how we will do.if possible please explain that scenario also.

Comment: Just checking your third paragraph: You did run `ALTER TABLE tblname AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483648;` ???

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE t_keyword_stat_ga\G` and post it in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Step 1: Backup Your Data
-- Make sure to backup your data before proceeding with any changes to the table structure.

-- Step 2: Alter the Column Type
-- Change the column type from INT to BIGINT to accommodate larger values.
ALTER TABLE t_keyword_stat_ga MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT;

-- Step 3: Reset Auto-increment Value
-- Reset the auto-increment value to start from a desired value to prevent gaps.
ALTER TABLE t_keyword_stat_ga AUTO_INCREMENT = 2147483648;

-- Step 4: Monitor Inserts
-- After making the changes, monitor inserts into the table to ensure they're functioning as expected.
```